# Writing plugins/extensions for IBM HttpServer

Tags: apache, plugins, ibmhttpserver

We want to write a custom plugin/extension for `IBM HTTP Server`. Our aim is to intercept all the requests that goes through the `HTTP Server` and add some `header/cookie` information to the `HTTP Request` and `Responses`. 
Is it possible to write this in `Java` language? Can you please share some thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write such an extension in C. The best references would be mod_headers /  mod_rewrite / mod_setenvif from vanilla Apache HTTP Server.